# Voltage comparator approach

Tags: voltage, comparator, negative-voltage

I am building a self biased tube amp. It has an adjustable negative bias of about -32 to -67 Vdc for various tubes. The power supply side has some bult in safeties to make sure there's always a negative supply. However if a diode in the - supply decides to go bad none of the safeties will help.

I was thinking that a voltage comparator could be used and say open a NO relay to cut power to the 500 Vdc B+ if the negative voltage dropped below an adjustable value (meaning becoming more positive than we want - guessing -32 to -67).
It would be by far safer for saving a runaway tube.

I know very little about what might be required to make something like this work.

Does anyone know of a schematic that might readily adapt or a more simple solution?

Comment: Please post a schematic

Comment: You are proposing to use a **semiconductor** part in a **tube** amplifier?  Horrors.  That might work -- a schematic would be helpful.  You could also use a suitable relay, but finding one with a small enough hysteresis to turn off reliably would be a challenge (i.e., a "48V" relay is guaranteed to turn _on_ at 48V, but it may not turn _off_ until it gets down to 24V or less).

Comment: @TimWescott The less extreme audiophile market is perfectly happy with semiconductors as long as they're not in the main signal path. Some of them are even fine with it in the signal path as long as it's not the main amplifying element!

Comment: @TimWescott [This one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00ADR2DTG) uses semiconductors with a vacuum tube. Pretty commonly found for the hoi polloi. I have one mostly because I started electronics when I could not get any transistors and only had vacuum tubes to deal with and it's a nod to that time for me. And it is cute. No other reason. ;)

Comment: The negative bias circuit found at https://www.valvewizard.co.uk/bias.html is the 2nd one down on the page (posting from my android will not allow me to add a new line)   and yes, i would like to keep all out of the audio signal path,  i have larger reservoir caps (100uf) but imagine there would be some ripple as its fed from half wave rectifier (single diode) ... it will take me sometime to digest your responce but i dont see a way to adjust (depending on tube and required negative bias voltage) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hearth's solution is good as long as due care is taken with the component parameters. eg an LDO safely dealing with 67V+ of input voltage will need proper design. And the relay is operated from the negative bias supply so care needs to be taken with current drain.

Below is a discrete circuit that should meet the need - and which also requires care with some components. A single transistor (Q1) can be used **IF** the -ve bias supply has enough current capacity t operate a relay. Such low coil current relays are available, but as an alternative this circuit drives a relay from a small +ve supply (say 12V or other).

**Operation:**

When -ve bias voltage magnitude is adequate Q1 turns on, turning Q2 off and Q3 on, operating RLY1 and turning on HT supply.
Q1 is shown as an MPSA92 which is rated at -300V and 500 mA.
Other pnp transistors could be used **provided that** voltage rating is adequate.

"V+ low voltage is sufficient to operate the relay. Operation from the HV plate supply is possible but not advisable.
I've assumed an approximate +12V supply, but almost any value can be designed for.

With Q1  off Q2 is turned on by R6.
With Q1 on R6 and R3 divide the difference of (V_low_v+ and -ve bias supply) in a ratio of about 2:1 (as shown) . So eg for a -65V bias and +12V relay supply. Vtotal is 77V and the R6:R3 point is at ABOUT +12 - (12+65)*2/3 ~~= -35V. Dx (1N4007 or other) clamps this at just below ground.
As shown this would operate Q2 at a bias of anywhere below about -15V ! -  ie far too little bias. Decreasing R6 or increasing R3 increases the magnitude of the required bias voltage to initiate HT application.

Lowering the value of R3 increases the load on the bias supply.
Increasing R6 reduces the base drive for Q2 - probably OK.
Resistor dissipations are relatively modest.
Transistor current gains (Betas) limit the upper magnitudes of R6 and R5 .

So, as with many apparently simple circuits there is a little bit of 'juggling;' required.
But, very doable.

If you can advise the desired V+low voltage to operate the relay (+12VDC?) then I can give a more final value for various resistors.

Component cost apart from relay is about $US1.

A reverse diode of suitable voltage rating across the relay contacts may be wise.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA2XqU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This is great! It took me a while to realize that the solution by hearth was powered by the bias circuit, which worried me. Im sure for nothing but if one diode failed my tube and that circuit would be useless.  The negative bias is very low current, needing a single diode and a cap or two. I didn't think that arrangement would satisfy the coil of a relay.. I think i may start looking for a suitable relay and small transformer now! Thank you for your input!

Comment: @Hoops  An optocoupler could be used to translate Q1 activation into the drive fir a MOSFET at Q3 - but what I have shown should work well. || If you want a better defined on/off voltage something like a TL431 could be used for Q1 - but you need to have some way to deal with the -ve bias voltage being greater than a TL431 will tolderate. Doable, with due thought.

Comment: @Hoops Ah, I thought being powered by the bias circuit would be a bonus! I'm generally a fan of self-powered circuits when practical, so I tried not to introduce any additional power supplies. But if you have other power supplies available, it's probably better to use those.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't very difficult, really.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1RwHh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can set the trip voltage of this by changing the R1/R2 ratio. These internal-reference comparators are really handy for jobs like this. Just pick any suitable MOSFET.

I've left off bypass capacitors and the MOSFET gate pulldown resistor.

You may want to use separate LDOs for the comparator and the relay; you'll waste less power using a 24 V relay than a 5 V one, but the comparator may not be able to function on 24 V.

Since the comparator isn't ground-referenced, you may encounter glitches if the negative rail is noisy. Adding some capacitance at the comparator's input may mitigate this, though it'll also slow the response.

Comment: The negative bias circuit found at https://www.valvewizard.co.uk/bias.html

Comment: The negative bias circuit found at https://www.valvewizard.co.uk/bias.html is the 2nd one down on the page (posting from my android will not allow me to add a new line)   and yes, i would like to keep all out of the audio signal path,  i have larger reservoir caps (100uf) but imagine there would be some ripple as its fed from half wave rectifier (single diode) ... it will take me sometime to digest your responce but i dont see a way to adjust (depending on tube and required negative bias voltage) ...

Comment: The negative rail can be -67 V.  What LDO can handle that?

Comment: @AnalogKid [Any of these](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/power-management-pmic/voltage-regulators-linear-low-drop-out-ldo-regulators/699?s=N4IgjCBcoKwOwGYqgMZQGYEMA2BnApgDQgD2UA2iAExVgwAMVIxtCAbA8%2BPfW3BMQAcMQQBY4XMVUEBOLtLhsEEljLCj2XNjLZU5LRTKqj5cGGw4gAusQAOAFyggAyvYBOASwB2AcxABfQKA), for instance.

Comment: @Hoops Nothing but the relay is anywhere near the audio signal path here. As I said in my answer, you can adjust the trip point by changing the R1/R2 divider ratio.

Comment: Hearth, i fully understand that the relay would be the only thing in the audio path, my previous response was directed at another reply.. I will try to figure the bypass and pulldown components you mentioned and see if i can choose some parts to breadboard... that said, is there anything you can point me to that might  show a little more detail? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Hoops Wht do you need more detail on?

Comment: Silver patter response would be complete 
schematic with component values and part numbers.. Teaching folks to fish, a fuller schematic so i can chew one bite at a time... my EE knowledge is very basic, had to look up what an LDO was and how its used.. still quite unsure but have something to go on. I also researched the pulldown resistor for the mosfet, think I understand. bypass caps would the next bridge i need to jump off.. im unsure of where they would be needed. Caps pass AC & block dc, as far as i can tell AC wouldn’t enter the picture so cant see where a bypass cap would be required..

Comment: @Hoops Pretty much every IC needs a bypass cap connected between its power supply and ground pins. This can be thought of as a filter, but it's maybe easier to consider it as a buffer on the power supply, to provide power quickly when needed where the power supply can only respond more slowly. Linear regulators in general, and especially LDOs, have pretty strict requirements on the input and output capacitors, so I'm not going to make recommendations on that without knowing what regulator is being used.

Comment: @Hoops As for the part numbers, at a glance (make sure to double check suitability yourself!) I might use an ADCMP356 or a MIC842 for the comparator, maybe a DMN10H220 for the MOSFET, and finding a suitable high-voltage relay I will leave up to you.

Comment: You rock! Ty so very much. The LDO datasheet should give me that i would guess.. the Two resistors im guessing could be potentiometers and if the values worked out maybe even one single pot? Would be nice :-) will gather datasheets to try and cobble a schematic up.. hoping may be even ltspice can maybe help me understand how the circuit behaves .. ty so very much again!